# The greatest volume of a prism inside a sphere

Tags: calculus

Find the greatest volume of a triangular prism inside a sphere of radius length 5 cm such that all the vertices of the prism touch the inner surface if the sphere where the base of the prism is an equilateral triangle ?
My turn :
The greatest volume happens when the prism is symmetric about the plane which passes through the greatest circle of the sphere , so , let center of the sphere is M$(0,2.5,0)$
Then 
One vertex of the prism will be A$(\frac{-2.5}{\sqrt{3}},0,h)$
But MA = r = 5
$$(\frac{2.5}{\sqrt{3}})^2 + (2.5)^2 + h^2 = 25$$
$$h = \frac{5\sqrt{6}}{3}$$
But the height of the prism is 2h , then
The height is $H = \frac{10\sqrt{6}}{3}$ and the side length os the base $= 5\sqrt{3}$
The volume $$= B.A \times H = \frac{375}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Is this solution correct ?